# Сортировка пользовательского типа

Tags: stl, vector, c++

Помогите разобраться с проблемой. Есть некоторый пользовательский класс:

```
 class gamer: public human, public points
    {
     public:
       gamer(char *name = NULL, int point = 0);
       gamer(const gamer&);
       ~gamer();
       int operator < (const gamer&);
    };
```

Создается STL vector из элементов этого типа. Затем вызывается алгоритм sort для этого вектора:

```
 std::vector<gamer> vect;
 sort(vect.begin(), vect.end());
```

Компилятор кидает ошибку:

> ошибка: passing 'const gamer' as
> 'this' argument of 'int
> gamer::operator<(const gamer&)'
> discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Компилятор ругается, на то что operator< не константный. Нужно определить его, как:

```
bool operator < (const gamer&) const;
```

Answer (score 1):

`operator <` должен быть константной функцией: `operator < (...) const`, а также возвращать не int, а bool (см. [тут](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/))